# Reshape the data to result in only a single row

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have a dataframe (df) which is in long/tall format like so

Input:

```
ID  entity_id  type
A1  1001       husband
A1  1002       wife
A1  1003       brother
A1  1004       son
A2  2005       husband
A2  2006       son
```

I want this to be in wide format, I did the following

Because Reshape can't handle duplicates (defaults to count) I added a dummy column

```
df$dummy <- seq_len(now(df))

df_wide <- dcast(df, dummy + ID ~ type, value.var="entity_id")
```

This is what I got:

```
dummy ID  husband wife  brother son
1     A1  1001    NA    NA      NA
2     A1  NA      1002  NA      NA
3     A1  NA      NA    1003    NA
```

What I wanted:

```
dummy ID  husband wife brother son
1     A1  1001    1002 1003    1004
2     A2  2005    NA   NA      2006
```

## EDIT1 SessionINFO()

```
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tidyr_0.4.1    reshape2_1.4.1 dplyr_0.4.3    RMySQL_0.10.8  DBI_0.3.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.3     magrittr_1.5   R6_2.1.2       assertthat_0.1 parallel_3.2.4 tools_3.2.4    Rcpp_0.12.4    stringi_1.0-1  stringr_1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand why you add the dummy column (and I assume you meant to write `df$dummy` instead of `df_dummy` for it). But the following seems to give the result you are looking for:

```
library(reshape2)

df <- read.delim(text="ID  entity_id  type
                 A1  1001       husband
                 A1  1002       wife
                 A1  1003       brother
                 A1  1004       son
                 A2  2005       husband
                 A2  2006       son", sep="")

dcast(df, ID ~ type, value.var="entity_id")
  ID brother husband  son wife
1 A1    1003    1001 1004 1002
2 A2      NA    2005 2006   NA
```

---

Edit: with your revised data in which there are multiple brothers and sons, I would suggest the following (---assuming that you still want to have everything in one row---):

**Solution 1: putting everything into one cell:**

```
df <- read.delim(text="ID  entity_id  type
A1  1001       husband
A1  1002       wife
A1  1003       brother
A1  1005       brother
A1  1004       son
A1  1006       son
A2  2005       husband
A2  2006       son", sep="")

dcast(df, ID ~ type, value.var="entity_id", 
      fun.aggregate = function(...) paste0(..., collapse = "_"))
  ID   brother husband       son wife
1 A1 1003_1005    1001 1004_1006 1002
2 A2              2005      2006
```

Here, I aggregated multiple instances by just pasting their IDs together. I don't know what you want to do with this later, so I don't know if this is a useful table for you. I just want to point out one possibility. Needless to say, you can change the aggregation function to suit your needs. For instance, instead of pasting them together, you could put them into a list.

```
dcast(df, ID ~ type, value.var="entity_id", fun.aggregate = list)
  ID    brother husband        son wife
1 A1 1003, 1005    1001 1004, 1006 1002
2 A2               2005       2006
```

**Solution 2: add columns:**

```
library(dplyr)
new.df <- df %>% group_by(ID, type) %>% 
                 mutate(type_num = paste(type, 1:n(), sep="_"))   
dcast(new.df, ID ~ type_num, value.var="entity_id")
  ID brother_1 brother_2 husband_1 son_1 son_2 wife_1
1 A1      1003      1005      1001  1004  1006   1002
2 A2        NA        NA      2005  2006    NA     NA
```

Comment: Yes you are correct on your comment about adding "df$dummy". Will test the answer and get back to you

Comment: The above code works, but dcast on the dataset I am using gives the results as I have mentioned before

Comment: Loading all your packages with similar versions did not invalidate the above solution. The only remaining difference is the `R` version itself, which is unlikely to account for any difference. Switching back and forth from factors to characters do not change anything either. So it seems that your data is different. I can only use the data you have provided. ;) If your error is not reproducable with this data, could you fix the data so that your issue is reproducable?

Comment: Yes, I will look into this and get back to you, thanks for the help

Comment: I am too embarrassed for this, but it turns out, there are multiple sons, and brother for the same id. I think I should delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

A major oversight on my part, but in the interest of someone like me in future.

The above issue will occur only if you have multiple entries for the same type, that is in the example above my actual data looks something like this

```
ID  entity_id  type
A1  1001       husband
A1  1002       wife
A1  1003       brother
A1  1005       brother
A1  1004       son
A1  1006       son
A2  2005       husband
A2  2006       son
```

Notice there are two sons and brothers:

```
since 'dcast' can't figure out how to resolve this, it ends up creating another row
```